# Find the $[E_1 : F_1]$ for $F_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3 i)$ and splitting field $E_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

$Q)$ $f(x) = x^6 -3, F_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3 i)$. Let the $E_1 = SF(f / F_1)$.($E_1$ means splitting field of the $f$ over $F_1 $ ). Find the $[E_1 : F_1]$

---

My answer is $6$. Let me explain why I get that result.

Firstly, All the roots of the $f$ are $\{\alpha \omega^i \vert 0 \leq i \leq5 \}$ $\Rightarrow$  $SF(f/\mathbb Q) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)$(Here the $\alpha = \sqrt[6] 3, w= e^{2 \pi i \over 6}$)

I easily checked the $F_1 \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)$. By the way, the $E_1$ is a splitting field over the $F_1$ so does the $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)$, I.e. both are splitting field over the $F_1$ for $f$, therefore We can get $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega) = E_1$. Surely $[E_1 : \mathbb{Q}] = [E_1 : \mathbb{Q}(\omega) ][\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6 \cdot \phi(6) = 12 $

Since the $[E_1 : \mathbb{Q}] = [E_1 : F_1][F_1 : \mathbb{Q}]$ and $[F_1 : \mathbb{Q}] =2$, So the answer is $6$

But the answer was $12$  What did I wrong?

I guess questioner of this question who claim the answer is $12$ makes a wrong conclusion. Because, I can't find my any mistakes in my solution yet. What do you think about that? Is my solution right?

Comment: How did you check that $F_1 \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \omega)$?

Comment: @DanielHast Because $\omega=\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2} $?

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me.

Comment: @DanielHast, like shivering soldier's answer we can check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me, so I would assume the other person made an error. To remove just about any remaining doubt, the following [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) code verifies that the degree is indeed $6$:

```
A.<x> = QQ[]
F.<w> = NumberField(x^2 + 3)   # F = Q(w), where w^2 + 3 = 0
B.<y> = F[]
E.<a> = NumberField(y^6 - 3)   # E = F(a), where a^6 - 3 = 0
E.relative_degree()            # [E : F] equals 6
E.is_galois_relative()         # is true, indicating that E/F is a Galois extension
```